# Why python pyserial put ø at the beginning of the string send?

Tags: python, string, pyserial

I have a bug  :o Searching long time but no answer !

My Rpi send commands to my Moteino gateway via serial and pyserial librairie.
My Moteino gateaway wait for these commands and proceed.

So, I can send and received in the both way but.

When I send a string from Rpi to Moteino, pyserial put a "**none**" or "**slash zero**" **ø** at the beginning of the string.
For example :

***Python code***

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
port =                 serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0',baudrate=115200,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=0)

port.flushOutput()
#Ecriture de la pré-commande "LMPCDE"
cde = "LMPCDE\r\n"
cde.encode('ascii','strict')
print cde
port.write(cde )
time.sleep(.1)
data = port.readline()
print data
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

port = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0',baudrate=115200,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=0)

port.flushOutput()
#Ecriture de la pré-commande "LMPCDE"
cde = "LMPCDE\r\n"
print cde
port.write(cde)
time.sleep(.1)
data = port.readline()
print data
```

Moteino code wait for command string read it and send it to RPI.

So:
    print cde
Prompt **LMPCDE**
and 
    print data
Prompt **øLMPCDE**

I use Python 2.7.3.

Why python pyserial put ø at the beginning of the string sent ?  :o

I can modify the moteino code to erase the first char but even if it's the easy way I don't think it's the good way as I don't understand why !

I find an other bug !

I run the python script via command line (Putty).

If I open an other Putty instance and run minicom "minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0" and run in the first console python script, there is no **ø** added to LMPCDE command. Of course as the serial input is redirected to minicom, I need to pass other string command via minicom.

Here is the entire code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
#Importation des librairies
import MySQLdb
import serial
import time
#import string

#Mes Fonctions
def convertstring(mystring):
    if len(mystring) == 3:
        mystring = "0" + mystring
    elif len(mystring) == 2:
        mystring = "00" + mystring
    elif len(mystring) == 1:
        mystring = "000" + mystring
    return mystring

#Connexion à la base de donnees
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx",                db="logsensorsvalues")  #Password with specials char like (&,@,# ...)
# you must create a Cursor object. It will let,
# you execute all the queries you need
cursor = db.cursor() 
# Use all the SQL you like
cursor.execute("SELECT Far_Red,Red,Red_Orange,Green,Blue,UV_410,UV_395 FROM ledlampvalues Order by ID desc limit 1")
# Values received
rows = cursor.fetchall()
#Fermeture de la base de donnees
cursor.close()
db.close()
#lecture de rows
commandstring=""
for row in rows:
    FarRed = convertstring(str(row[0]*10))  #x10 pour conserver l'architecture du protocole
    Red = convertstring(str(row[1]*10))
    RedOrange = convertstring(str(row[2]*10))
    Green = convertstring(str(row[3]*10))
    Blue = convertstring(str(row[4]*10))
    UV1 = convertstring(str(row[5]*10))
    UV2 = convertstring(str(row[6]*10))
#Formatage de la chaine de caracteres
commandstring = "C" + "F" + FarRed + "R" + Red + "O" + RedOrange + "G" + Green + "B" + Blue + "U" + UV1 + "V" + UV2 + "E" #+ "\r\n"

#Serial Port http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.FileLike.readline
#Possible values for the parameter timeout:
#timeout = None: wait forever
#timeout = 0: non-blocking mode (return immediately on read)
#timeout = x: set timeout to x seconds (float allowed)
serialport = serial.Serial()

serialport.port = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
serialport.baudrate = 115200
serialport.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
serialport.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
serialport.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
serialport.timeout = 0            #non-blocking mode (return immediately on read)
serialport.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
serialport.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
serialport.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
serialport.writeTimeout = 0     #timeout for write

try:
    serialport.open()
except Exception , e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if serialport.isOpen():
    print "Port Open"
    try:
        #Pay attention to the flush order : Output before Input
        serialport.flushOutput() #flush output buffer, aborting current output and discard all that is in buffer
        serialport.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        #Ecriture de la pré-commande "LMPCDE"   /// cde.encode('ascii','strict')
        print serialport.write('LMPCDE')
        serialport.flushInput()
        time.sleep(.1)

                #----------------------------DEBUG ZONE----------------------------
        #data = serialport.readline()
        #print data
        while serialport.inWaiting() > 0:
        print serialport.read()
        #-------------------------------END--------------------------------

        while serialport.inWaiting() > 0:
            data = serialport.readline()
            if data.startswith("Expecting"):
                print data
                #Waiting for an acknowledgement from Node
                while serialport.inWaiting() > 0:
                    data = serialport.readline()
                    if data.startswith("ok"):
                        print "Sending Command"
                        serialport.write(commandstring)

        time.sleep(.1)

        #Waiting for an acknowledgement from Node
        while serialport.inWaiting() > 0:
            data = serialport.readline()
            if data.startswith("ok"):
                print data

        serialport.close()          
    except Exception , e1:
        print "error open serial port: " + str(e1)
        exit()
else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Comment: Please fix spelling errors, markdown-syntax and clean up the post a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you may try to debug the issue:

- flush serial input with the command `port.flushInput()` right after `port.flush.Output()`
- Use `port.read()` that would read from serial port symbol by symbol

`while 1:`

```
    ch = port.read()
    #Condition for end of line, any other condition may be here
    if ch = '\n'
        #Terminate while loop
        break
```

Comment: You are right ! In first time I try port.flushInput and after port.flushOutput() and nothing. Invert the order and all is good ! I don't understand !

Comment: flushOutput() causes the serial port output buffer to be sent, I think that you device answers with the strange symbol and it appeart in the serial port input buffer. Then you flush input buffer and everything afterward works fine. So the correct order it to flushOutput, then flushInput, as I said in my reply

Comment: I will try this "medic" and, of course, if there is no more serial bug I will upvote your answer and accept it !Thanks a lot ! No more headaches !

Comment: Check my explanation in the comment above why you should `flushOutput()` and then `flushInput()`. So that's what you exactly did

Comment: I flushOutput, flushInput then send my command and read the incoming using while 1: print pot.read(). And it's seems there is always the bug, infinite carriage return read and Putty console closed.

Comment: You need exit condition out of while loop if you use port.read() like the number of symbols to read or whatever else. See no problem with using port.readLine() in your case

Comment: I do an other debugging. As I have and USB-Serial adapter I used it to communicate with my Moteino gateway. Same code, but "/dev/ttyUSB0". And it's working good, no bug, no ø.

Comment: I think the bug is in relation with DTR

Comment: Did flashing help or you experience the same problem as before?

Comment: If i use FTDI adapter, the same problem occur but more heratic. I use Raspberry Pi & Raspbian with LAMP.

Comment: Have no Rapsberry device, so can't comment on specifics here